# Flutter Can't define a const constructor for a class with non-final fields

Tags: flutter

I need to use setState in my code if i use its showing that

```
The method 'setState' isn't defined for the type 'ProductDetailPage'.
```

i know whats the issue its because i need to change the statelesswidget to statefullwidget. But there is one more issue if i change the stateless widget to statefull widget its showing error

```
Can't define a const constructor for a class with non-final fields.
```

MY code

```
part of '../pages.dart';

class ProductDetailPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProductDetailPageState createState() => _ProductDetailPageState();
}

class _ProductDetailPageState extends State<ProductDetailPage> {

  final Product product;

  const ProductDetailPage({Key key, @required this.product}) : super(key: key); //showing error here


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    double stackWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double stackHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              buildCarousel(context),

            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: () {
          //todo: Get.to(CartPage());
        },
        backgroundColor: kPrimaryColor,
        label: Text(
          'product.addtocart',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.button,
        ).tr(),
      ),
    );
  }


  SideInAnimation buildCarousel(BuildContext context) {
    double stackWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double stackHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return SideInAnimation(
      1,
      child: Container(
        color: kCardImageBCColor,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: stackHeight * 0.3,
              child: Image.asset(product.images[0]),
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                ...List.generate(product.images.length,
                        (index) => buildSmallProductPreview(index, context)),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(height: stackHeight * 0.02,)
          ],
        ),

      ),
    );
  }

  GestureDetector buildSmallProductPreview(int index, BuildContext context) {
    int selectedImage = 0;
    double stackWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double stackHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          selectedImage = index;
        });
      },
      child: AnimatedContainer(
        duration: Duration(seconds: 1),

        margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
        height: stackHeight * 0.07,
        width: stackWidth * 0.15,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          border: Border.all(
              color: kPrimaryColor.withOpacity(selectedImage == index ? 1 : 0)),
        ),
        child: Image.asset(product.images[index]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I dont know why its showing error if use statefull widget and dont use setState its working fine. But i must need to setState so i must need to go on stateFull widget. And i need to solve error xD

Comment: You have placed the widget constructor inside the state. Move the constructor to the widget. `const ProductDetailPage({Key key, @required this.product}) : super(key: key);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the final variable and the constructor in the ProductDetailPage class.
Like this:

```
class ProductDetailPage extends StatefulWidget {

  final Product product;

  const ProductDetailPage({Key key, @required this.product}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ProductDetailPageState createState() => _ProductDetailPageState();
}

class _ProductDetailPageState extends State<ProductDetailPage> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {...}
}
```